# Heap sort algorithm complexity on non unique elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I wanted to know how heap sort will work on an array with uniform elements.I am talking in context of complexity and running.

Comment: What are uniform elements?

Comment: Maybe a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 0):

An array with uniform elements in this case is an instance of a best-case, so the complexity is going to be O(n*log(n)) ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort))

That's in theory.

Of course, in practice, you will notice an improvement compared to the average case (which has the same complexity), because you no longer have swapping between elements.

If you want to see for yourself how big the improvement is, I suggest implementing the algorithm and trying it for the best, worst and average case.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know in a different perspective like for example when applying quick sort on an array with the all the same elements, in the partitioning phase if we always choose the pivot (the value to partition the array) as the middle index value of the array, then we get a balanced recursion tree right? thats a modification we can make to reduce the total iterations. But i want to know what can I do in case of heap sort on an array with similar elements to reduce iterations or improve running cost?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question ... Could you give an example of how the array you are trying to sort looks like ? Because I am not sure I know what you mean when you say similar elements.

Comment: likean array of length 20 consisting of all 2's